# Not able to access globally installed node module

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-install, ubuntu-19.04

I tried to install [@hapi/joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) using command

```
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js$ sudo npm install @hapi/joi -g
+ @hapi/joi@16.1.7
updated 1 package in 2.833s
```

I am able to see installed `@hapi/joi` in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

```
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js/tmp$ npm root -g
/usr/local/lib/node_modules

alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js/tmp$ npm list -g @hapi/joi
/usr/local/lib
`-- @hapi/joi@16.1.7  

alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js$ tree /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hapi/joi/ -L 1
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hapi/joi/
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── dist
├── lib
├── LICENSE.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── README.md

3 directories, 4 files
```

But I am not able to access it

```
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js$ node
> var Joi = require('@hapi/joi'); // this is not working
{ Error: Cannot find module '@hapi/joi'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
> 
> 
> var Joi = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hapi/joi') // This is working
undefined
```

My `node` and `npm` are

```
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js$ which node
/usr/bin/node
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js$ node -v
v10.15.2
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js$ npm -v
6.11.3

alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js$ echo $NODE_PATH # this shows nothing

alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cr1xxx:~/tmp/js$ node
> process['env']['PATH']
'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
>
```

Why I am getting `Error: Cannot find module '@hapi/joi'`? How to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What's the output of `npm root -g` ?

Comment: Please also post the output of `npm list -g @hapi/joi`

Comment: posted in question

Comment: What's the output of `which node` ?

Comment: updated `which node` in question

Comment: What if you try to `require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@hapi/joi')` ? Does that work? If it works, please post the output of `echo $NODE_PATH`

Comment: Whwre is the package .lock

Comment: @AnkitKumarRajpoot: I installed globally so dont know.

Comment: @AlokSinghMahor I noticed that `require`ing using the absolute path worked, so please post the output of `echo $NODE_PATH`.

Comment: @EyalC: updated `NODE_PATH` in question

Comment: Try to print `process.env.NODE_PATH` after running `node`

Answer (score 1):

Adding `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to `NODE_PATH` make it work

```
# Add this line in yuor ~/.bashrc
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
```

or

```
# Add this line in yuor ~/.bashrc
export NODE_PATH="`npm root -g`:$NODE_PATH"
```

or

```
// Add this line at top in your node.js script
module.paths.push('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/')
```

Tested on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu) 20.04, This should work in other [Linux distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your user folder? I have a `node_module` folder here `/Users/<username>/node_modules` It might be in there.

And you would have to change the `$PATH` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

you should have to use npm init it will make package.json then you can run you js file.